# Is this sentence wrong: "You are the only friend that he will listen to at all."?

Tags: grammar

I am doing an grammar exercise:

```
You are the only friend ___ he will listen to at all.

A) where 
B) whom 
C) which 
D) that
```

I chose B), but the answer key says D). Any explanation?

Comment: Bad test? The antecedent is a person, so *whom* works. So does *that*. Consider the song "You're the One that I Want". (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_864Y7G4tk)

Comment: There are some vestigial pseudo-rules from the bad old days of extreme prescriptivist grammar that insist that "that" must be used in any situation where a who/whom/that word choice appears at the beginning of a restrictive clause. The claim has no merit and amounts to an attempt by overzealous would-be arbiters of language to impose a rule where none exists. As deadrat says, either "whom" or "that" works fine in the blank of the exercise question, although "that" is surely more common in everyday speech involving constructions of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you and would also use "whom" when talking about a person and not a thing. However you can use "that" instead of "who" in a relative clause sentence, but in a test it would have been better to include both answers as correct.
Referring to the Raymond Murphy's English Grammar in Use:
"We use **who** in a relative clause when we are talking about people (*not* things):

- The woman **who lives next door** is a doctor.
  You can also use **that** (instead of **who**), but you can't use which for people:
- The woman **that lives next door** is a doctor. (*not* the woman which)"